Can you setup your Route to use sticky session and load balance at the same time in openshift?
My Application uses an HAProxy route to load balance incoming requests to one or more pods. Since sticky session is enabled by default, its only been sending multiple user request to a single pod. I want it to be able to send a User to the same pod if it has visited before (Sticky session), and new Users to the pods with the least connection using the "leastconn" load balancer algorithm. Is this possible in Red Hat Openshift?
My Route:
kind: Route
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: my-project
  annotations:
    haproxy.router.openshift.io/balance: leastconn
spec:
  host: myhost.com
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: my-app
    weight: 100
  port:
    targetPort: http-8080
  tls:
    termination: edge
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Redirect
  wildcardPolicy: None


Using sticky sessions in OpenShift, it is not possible to guarantee that a new connection will go to a different Pod than the one that is serving the sticky session.
As per the documentation, you use the haproxy.router.openshift.io/balance: source annotation to enable sticky sessions on your route. This annotation uses the source load balancing strategy, which hashes the source IP address and uses that to distribute requests among the Pods. You can only enable one of the leastconn, source, or roundrobin load balancing strategies.
Therefore, it is possible that a new connection comes and the source IP address hashing algorithm that is applied determines that the new connection should go to the same Pod currently serving the sticky session connection, regardless of how many sessions it’s already serving.

@Christoper Since the new connections do not have the cookies that enables those sticky session, is the router not able to make a new decision so that the connection gets forwarded to the pod that has the least connection traffic if I am using leastconn load balancing strategy on my Route.

The “decision” the router makes is the sticky session algorithm, which hashes the source IP address and divides it by the weight of the destination Pods. When you set it to use a load balancing strategy of sticky session, the router only looks at the source IP of the new connection and sends it to the mathematical result of its hashing algorithm (corresponding to one of your destination Pods). It doesn’t even look at total connections per Pod, it’s only looking at the source IP. It’s similar to a HashMap, except instead of assigning a value to some key, it’s assigning a connection to a Pod.

So, if it is looking at the mathematical result of hashing the connection IP and the weight of the destination pods, should the part of the assigning the connection be somewhat random? Currently, in my case no matter where I start the connection from it is being assigned to the same pod, is this a coincidence?

Is guaranteeing the connection to be distributed equally among pods cannot be guaranteed using sticky sessions in openshift, what would be the alternative to this. I want to keep the sticky sessions but would also want to distribute new oncoming traffic in a load balanced fashion, is enabling a data grid between the backend pods the only option?
